# Select con la misma clase

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo 2 select con la misma `clase` y diferente `id`, cuando quiero que primero me salga el 2 select y presionando el 2 boton  no es capaz de tomar el valor, pero si lo hago con el primer select y el primer boton si toma el valor. 
¿CÓmo hago para que me tome el valor independiente de cual es primero?

aqui un demo de lo que llevo [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eduardzora/7ddo41g3/2/)

Comment: Hola @Eduard sería un poco más útil añadir el demo aquí que enviar a una página externa

Comment: Además de traer el código a la propia pregunta, estaría bien que clarificases un poco qué es lo que quieres. He leído varias veces la pregunta y aún no me queda claro qué es lo que estás intentando hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario que selecciones ambos desplegables 
para poder dibujar. Simplemente agrega otro data atributo por ejemplo `ref` el cual mantenga relación con `rel` del botón presionado y así saber qué `select` y `canvas` seleccionar.

**Ejemplo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.draw').click(function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    var select = document.querySelector('select[ref="' + rel + '"]');

    draw(rel, $(select).val());
  });
});

function draw(rel, value) {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas[ref="' + rel + '"]');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  if (value === '2') {
    // Draw the face
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, 85, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";

    // Draw the left eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(75, 75, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw the right eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(114, 75, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw the mouth
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, 90, 26, Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // Write "Hello, World!"
    ctx.font = "30px Garamond";
    ctx.fillText("Hello, World!", 15, 175);

  }

  if (value == '4') {
    // Draw the face
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, 85, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";

    // Draw the left eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(75, 75, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw the right eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(114, 75, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw the mouth
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, 90, 26, Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // Write "Hello, World!"
    ctx.font = "30px Garamond";
    ctx.fillText("Hola, Mundo!", 15, 175);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="todo" ref="1">
  <option selected>Ingrese cant</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<div>
  <button class="draw" rel="1">Draw</button>
</div>

<div>
  <canvas ref="1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>


<select class="todo" ref="2">
  <option selected>Ingrese cant</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>


<div>
  <button class="draw" rel="2">Draw</button>
</div>

<div>
  <canvas ref="2" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta está correcta, y sin embargo el snippet no me dibuja el primer canvas. WTF

Comment: @amenadiel a mí me dibuja normal. El de arriba (siempre que selecciones 2) dibuja una cara amarilla y el de abajo (siempre que selecciones 4) dibuja una azul.

Comment: Hmmm funciona con algunos números. Con otros se superpone a la imagen anterior. Pero es problema de la función draw, claramente, así que está fuera del alcance de la pregunta

Comment: Sí, lo que pasa es que le falta limpiar el lienzo antes de volver a dibujar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar `:first` (Toma el primer elemento que se consiga con la clase) o `:last` (Toma el ultimo elemento con la clase) como:

```
var test = $('.todo:first').val();

var testy2 = $('.todo:last').val();
```

Aca esta tu ejemplo [actualizado](https://jsfiddle.net/p6t41c1r/)

***Nota:*** Aca es util porque solo tienes 2 si aumenta la cantidad de controles es mejor buscar otra alternativa, como crearles Ids unicos.

***Edit:***

Basado en tu comentario lo que peudes hacer es englobar cada select con los button en div separados asi:

```
<div>
  <select class="todo" id="ty">
    <option selected>Ingrese cant</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <button class="draw" id="draw" rel="1" data-select='1'>Draw</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <canvas  id="1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para luego via jQuery hacer esto:

```
var test = $(this).parent().parent().find('select').val();
```

Lo que hace es, vete al padre del padre (Este es el div que engloba cada seccion) busca el select, y dame su valor.

Codigo actualizado [aca](https://jsfiddle.net/p6t41c1r/3/)

Comment: Ese es el problema, que son mucho, es decir por medio de un input yo digo cuandos select me salen y hay es donde no me funciona

Comment: @Eduard Ya te doy otra solucion que habia pasado por alto

Comment: estoy pendiente

Comment: @Eduard Mira si asi te funciona ahora.